Memory management in Docker (Swarm)
We have a Docker Swarm (with a single node). The host has 32Gb memory available to it and some minimalistic swap file (4Gb or so). I'm noty sure why the host is the way it is, but maybe it's not relevant for the questions I have.
There are some memory-greedy containers running in Docker. Like, 4-5Gb RAM is required for one instance to operate when it is active. (Bioinformatics, with some large databases)
So, in a situation when we do not configure any memory limits on services, and we activate enough of container instances in parallell, bad things happen: I don't know exactly what the scenario is, but Docker ends up restarting everything, all of the containers. I'm assuming that everything gets starved for memory, and either the kernel kills something or Docker does - it doesn't really matter in the end, everybody dies.
My primary task is to avoid the "everybody dies" scenario. I'm not yet sure how we will define the strategy for calculating how many instances to allow to attempt run in parallell, that's a question for another day. For starters, I need to keep the OS and Docker operative, also so that they can kill memory-greedy offenders.
Now, if I give the service a memory limit below what it needs, it immediately starts to spill over to the swap, and since the swap file is tiny, soon it becomes full and the next memory-greedy process inside the container fails. Which is fine and correct. Now, the million-dollar question. How do I configure the service in terms of memory limit and number of replicas, so that the same behavior is achieved without involving the swap quite so soon? If I set memory limit to "enough" for an individual instance, all I achieve is that I get the system to swap like there's no tomorrow, and it is even worse than all docker services dying, actually. Please, help me understand this.
